# Enumeration error on Application.Restart()

Tags: vb.net, restart

The last time I worked on this app this worked, suddenly "Application.Restart" is no longer working.  I have no idea what its having a problem with, but the error is

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ckNotify.Checked Then
        CreateKey("HKCU\Software\Tool Inc\Inventory\Notify", "True")
        frmMain.Timer1.Enabled = True
    Else
        CreateKey("HKCU\Software\Tool Inc\Inventory\Notify", "False")
        frmMain.Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If

    frmMain.Label5.Text = "Stockroom view: " & Stockkey & ""

    Dim nodes As TreeNodeCollection = frmMain.TreeView1.Nodes
    Dim nodes2 As TreeNodeCollection = frmMain.TreeView2.Nodes
    If nodes.Count > 0 Then
        frmMain.TreeView2.SelectedNode = nodes2(0)
        frmMain.TreeView1.SelectedNode = nodes(0)
    End If

    If ReadKey("HKCU\Software\Tool Inc\Inventory\Stockroom") = ComboBox1.Text Then
        Close()
    Else
        CreateKey("HKCU\Software\Tool Inc\Inventory\Stockroom", ComboBox1.Text)

        Stockkey = ReadKey("HKCU\Software\Tool Inc\Inventory\Stockroom")

        Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("The application will need to close and re-open.  Click ok to continue", "Restart Needed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If result = DialogResult.No Then
            Close()
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Application.Restart()
        End If
    End If
    Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you posted. However, you exception message likely means you are modifying some collection in a `For Each` loop. Probably `Application.Restart` triggers some events that contains such a loop?

Comment: ...Quite possibly in that timer event

Comment: Well that's why I'm confused, I don't see a for each loop.  I also haven't changed this application in months.  The only difference between running it now and back when this worked was my Windows 7 PC i wrote it on is now Windows 10.

Comment: Could you maybe show us what happens in the timer?

Comment: Can't see any issue with the code you are showing. Did you having the debugger trigger on the exception so you get the exact location where it happens? A stack trace in that case may point to the issue. I guess the `Application.Restart` is only the point where the exception reaches your code.